# Groovy program to connect mongo db

Tags: mongodb, groovy

I am trying to connect mongodb using Groovy language but i am getting error like this (which is posted below) and i have added necessary jar file.I am using mongodb verion : mongodb-driver-3.2.2.jar .
Please help me to solve this problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/operation/OperationExecutor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run(CachedClass.java:69)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue(CachedClass.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getConstructors(CachedClass.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:223)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:168)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:158)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:241)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:859)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at com.sample.MongoService.client(MongoService.groovy:14)
    at com.sample.MongoService.collection(MongoService.groovy:21)
    at com.sample.MongoService$collection.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.sample.MongoDBController.method(MongoDBController.groovy:10)
    at com.sample.MongoDBController$method.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.sample.GroovyDemoApp.main(GroovyDemoApp.groovy:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.operation.OperationExecutor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

**Update :**

This is my Groovy code. with this code i am trying to connect Mongodb

```
// error is in this line . i .e - 
// The type com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation cannot be resolved.
// It is indirectly referenced from required .class files )
package com.sample

import com.mongodb.*

class MongoService { 
  private static MongoClient mongoClient 
  private static host = "localhost" //your host name 
  private static port = 27017 //your port no. 
  private static databaseName = "db"

  public static MongoClient client() {
    if(mongoClient == null){
        return new MongoClient(host,port)
    }else {
        return mongoClient
    }
  }

  public DBCollection collection(collectionName) {
    DB db = client().getDB(databaseName)
    return db.getCollection(collectionName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide more information. For example the code throwing the error would be very helpful. Please format the code when you post it.

Comment: Also, how are you running it, and how have you added the jar file?

Comment: Right, so that's the code. Now how are you running it, and how are you adding the jar to the classpath?

Comment: I am adding JAR file by right clicking on project >> Build path >>configure build path >> Add external jar ..                                                                                                                    The error is in first line i.e. (The type com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files)

Answer (score 2):

To use the MongoDB driver you can either use the JAR, or `@Grab` it from Maven.

### Using the JAR

To use the JAR, you need to add it to Groovy's classpath. This is done with the -cp argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy -cp /path/to/jar/file

println 'Hello'
```

### Using Maven

You can simply use Groovy's `@Grab` to take care of the dependency for you:

```
@Grab('org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.2.2')

println 'Hello'
```

### Working example

Here's a working example based on the code you posted:

```
@Grab('org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.2.2')

import com.mongodb.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.DBCollection
import com.mongodb.DB
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

class MongoService { 
    private MongoClient mongoClient 

    def host = "localhost" //your host name 
    def port = 27017 //your port no. 
    def databaseName = 'test'

    public MongoClient client() {
        mongoClient = mongoClient ?: new MongoClient(host, port) 

        return mongoClient
    } 

    public DBCollection collection(collectionName) { 
        DB db = client().getDB(databaseName)

        return db.getCollection(collectionName) 
    }
}

def service = new MongoService(databaseName: 'db')
def foo = service.collection('foo')

def data = [
    [firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe'],
    [firstName: 'Elvis', lastName: 'Presley']
].collect { it as BasicDBObject }

foo.insert(data)

foo.find().toArray().each {
    println it
}
```

I've never used MongoDB before, so whether my *use case* is useful or not is debatable.

Comment: After adding JAR in Groovy's classpath, i am getting same error as mentioned above .

Comment: @RakeshAR as we said above, you're going to have to show what you're doing. How are you running? How are you adding the jar? What is your small example of failing code. This is stackoverflow, not psychic-overflow...

Comment: Below is my Groovy code    package com.sample

import com.mongodb.*


class MongoService {
 private static MongoClient mongoClient
 private static host = "localhost"    //your host name
 private static port = 27017      //your port no.
 private static databaseName = "db"

 public static MongoClient client() {
  if(mongoClient == null){
   return new MongoClient(host,port)
  }else {
   return mongoClient
  }
 }

 public DBCollection collection(collectionName) {
  DB db = client().getDB(databaseName)
  return db.getCollection(collectionName)
 }
}

Comment: Ya i have tried using @Grab but i am getting same issue

Comment: First, next time please add your code to the question, not as a comment. I added a working example to my answer.