# I have written Mongo db connection code in NodeJS it works good but fails in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, jmeter

I Am trying to connect Jmeter to MongoDB using java script as scripting language but it fails.

I have tried same code in node JS and it works good but fails in Jmeter

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://10.80.47.101:27017';

 MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {

 if (err) throw err;

const db = client.db("scorecard");

db.listCollections().toArray().then((docs) => {

    console.log('Available collections:');
    docs.forEach((doc, idx, array) => { console.log(doc.name) });

}).catch((err) => {

    console.log(err);
}).finally(() => {

    client.close();
});
```

});

I am getting this error in Jmeter:

Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: :9:6 Expected : but found (
   if (err) throw err;
      ^ in  at line number 9 at column number 6

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? NodeJS style JavaScript is not going to work here. If you are intending to script actions to Jmeter using data read from a MongoDB instance then there is a [Groovy scripting interface](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/writing-jmeter-functions-in-groovy/), and of course you can include the Java Driver within the classpath. The embedded scripting engine used here for JavaScript just does not support the same things you are doing with NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn for your assistance
I intend to connect Jmeter to Mongo DB and perform some CRUD operations.
I didn't get this part  " you can include the Java Driver within the classpath" can u plz elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JMeter's possibility of executing JavaScript is quite limited to [Nashorn engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)), to wit your script will fail at the first line as [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) is not a part of JavaScript API, it's something from [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's not recommended to use languages other than Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) for any form of scripting

So instead of trying to load test your Mongo instance using JavaScript code you should rather:

1. Download [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) which matches your Mongo version and put it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
4. [Write your logic in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102618/groovy-program-to-connect-mongo-db), check the [JavaDoc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/overview-summary.html) for your particular Mongo Java Driver version for correct syntax

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)